# How to change the width of metro-ui website

Tags: html, css, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a application in which I use the metro-ui css. The width of the website is smaller than the screen of the browser. I want it to be as large as the screen with a padding of 15px on each side. To accomplish this I wrapped everything in body class as follows:

```
body {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The body element has a class of 'metro'. Besides that not much is happening. We can summarize the page as follows:

```
<link href="/Content/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/metro-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="metro">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
```

Somehow the screen has a width that is too small for a large screen, but I do not know which element I have to give a new width. I tried body, html and metro, but the only effect it has is that the display goes to the left, right or disappears without changing the site.

I hope someone that has experience with metro-ui can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Add this above the body

```
<style>
.metro
{
  //!important is probably not necessary 
  width:100% !important;  
  height:100% !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

on `.metro .container`
add `min-width:100%`